# Spark job collapses into a single partition but I do not understand why

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I am trying to tune a spark job.

I am using databricks to run it and at some point I see this picture:

[image]

Notice that in stage 12, I have only one partition- meaning there is no parallelism. How can I deduce the cause for this? To be sure, I do not have any 'repartition(1)' in my code.

Adding the (slightly obfuscated) code:

```
spark.read(cid, location).createOrReplaceTempView("some_parquets")

parquets = spark.profile_paqrquet_df(cid)

parquets.where("year = 2018 and month = 5 and day = 18 and sm_device_source = 'js'"
        .createOrReplaceTempView("parquets")

# join between two dataframes.  

spark.sql(
    """
        SELECT     {fields}
        FROM       some_parquets  
        WHERE      some_parquets.a = 'js' 
        AND        some_parquets.b = 'normal' 
        AND        date_f >= to_date('2018-05-01') 
        AND date_f < to_date('2018-05-05') 
        limit {limit}
    """.format(limit=1000000, fields=",".join(fields))
).createOrReplaceTempView("some_parquets")

join_result = spark.sql(
    """
        SELECT 
                   parquets.some_field, 
                   struct(some_parquets.*) as some_parquets
        FROM       some_parquets  
        LEFT ANTI JOIN some_ids ON some_parquets.sid = some_ids.sid 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN parquets ON some_parquets.uid = parquets.uid   
    """.format(some_ids=some_ids)
)

# turn items in each partition into vectors for machine learning
vectors = join_result \
    .rdd \
    .mapPartitions(extract)

# write vectors to file system. This evaluates the results
dump_vectors(vectors, output_folder)
```

Session construction:

```
spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("...") \
        .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 1000)
```

Comment: What kind of job is this? Looks like a case of skewed partitions. Can you try repartitioning the dataframe.

Comment: Would you, please, share a code?

Comment: We could help if you share what you are trying to run. Here its simple case of skew on a aggregating key. Maybe you can try changing the key or handle the skew separately and then union it to non skewed data

Comment: @VladislavVarslavans, added ther sliughtly obfuscated version of the code

Comment: @philantrovert, the question is where to repartition ? After each shuffle the partitioning changes. I added the code snippet above.

Comment: @Constantine, added the code

Comment: @Vitaliy which of the tables in the join query has skewed data on the joining key?

Comment: @Constantine, I guess this is what I need to find out. But I am unsure how to do it. Still learning, any direction would help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If anybody is still interested in the answer, in short it happens because of limit clause. Strangely limit clause collapses data into a single partition after the shuffle stage.

Just a sample run on my local spark-shell

```
scala> spark.sql("Select * from temp limit 1").rdd.partitions.size
res28: Int = 1

scala> spark.sql("Select * from temp").rdd.partitions.size
res29: Int = 16
```